# Understanding splitting lemma

Tags: exact-sequence

[Read this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_exact_sequence)  If the sequence is short exact, then it already has arrows $0 \to  \dots$ and $\dots \to 0$ which imply injectivity and surjectivity respectively, right?  So in that case there is already always such a map $t$.  So what am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write
$$ 0 \to A \xrightarrow{q} B \xrightarrow{r} C \to 0. $$

The first and last arrows imply injectivity and surjectivity of $q$ and $r$, respectively. This does not imply that there is a splitting.

Mathworld gives a [counterexample](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SplitExactSequence.html): 
$$ 0 \to \Bbb{Z}_2 \to \Bbb{Z}_4 \to \Bbb{Z}_2 \to 0 $$
where the first map takes $1\mapsto 2$. This is not a split SES because $\Bbb{Z}_4$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_2\oplus\Bbb{Z}_2$.

My geometric intuition is better than my algebraic intuition, so I tend to think of short exact sequences as analogues of fiber bundles. A split SES is special: It is like a trivializable fiber bundle. In general, one should not expect a SES to split; $B$ is generically formed by "twisting" $A$ and $C$ together.

Comment: That doesn't address my question directly.

Comment: First paragraph addresses your assertion directly. Next two paragraphs elaborate on why your belief is wrong. If you edit an argument for your belief that injectivity/surjectivity imply splitting into the question, I will be happy to alter my answer accordingly.